# Git rebase still showing merge commit

Tags: git

Given those 2 branches:

```
master
myfeature
```

When I'm done with `myfeature` I rebase on `master` like so:

`git rebase -i master`

Now to merge it on master:

```
git checkout master
git merge myfeature
git push origin master
```

Right after checking out master, it happens that some work has been merged by someone else.

If I pull before merging

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge myfeature
git push origin master
```

It keeps showing the merge commits in the logs.

Do I need to pull master before merging eventhough the branch was rebased?
How to get rid of the merge commits in this case?

Note git is configured with: `pull.rebase=true`

My full workflow is:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout -b myfeature
git add .
git commmit -m "myfeature"
git push origin myfeature
git rebase -i master
git checkout master
git pull origin master # ??
git merge myfeature
git push origin master
git branch -d myfeature
git push origin --delete myfeature
```

Comment: *"My full workflow is:..."* You overcomplicate things. after committing the feature you could simply do `push origin --force-with-lease myfeature:master` This will replace all the rest ou you procedure and fail if someone else made a commit to *master* meanwhile. In tha case you simply do `git fetch && git rebase origin/master` before repeating the push.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle All these commands have a meaning in my head. I'm often afraid of magical options I don't know about but this indeed looks like it could save a lot of my time! I'll try it for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fix the merge problem

You should pull the `master` branch just before doing your rebase.

Otherwise there can be some changes not taken into account into your rebase, and they will be merged.

What's more, in this case your rebase doesn't have any effect because the `myfeature` branch is already on top of the latest changes you pulled from origin.

After creating your branch :

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git rebase -i master myfeature
git checkout master
git merge myfeature
```

### Other remark

- Don't push the `myfeature` branch before your rebase. Otherwise your will end up having different histories between the local and remote branches.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/667200/877408) has further indications about that.

Comment: oh right. I was under the impression I had to be in myfeature to do the rebase. I'll try to do it in this order instead.

Comment: @gyc: `git rebase -i master myfeature` (or more generally, `git rebase <options> <onto-branch> <source-branch>`) actually runs `git checkout` on the source branch as its first step. So you *do* have to be "in myfeature", but you don't have to run `git checkout` first!

Comment: @torek this not what matthiasbe says.He is on master when rebase is ran. And I believe I need to pull master before the rebase, otherwise why would I have merge commits in my history?

Comment: @gyc: I'm afraid this topic is rather confusing in the first place, and trying to cram it all into comments just makes it worse, but: `git merge` *won't* run `git checkout` for you (ever), and `git pull` runs `git merge`, so for `git pull` you *must* be in the branch you intend to be in when `git pull` runs `git merge`. When you, manually, run `git rebase`, though, you can ask `git rebase` to first run `git checkout` for you. (I think it's generally wiser to do the separate commands, especially if you're still getting used to Git. But you *can* have rebase run `git checkout`.)

Comment: My first comment was pointing out that *your* first comment is correct in a technical sense, because `git rebase -i master myfeature` is equivalent to `git checkout myfeature; git rebase -i master`. (This means the last `git merge` command in matthiasbe's answer is a no-op.)

Comment: Thank you for this remark, I didn't know about this implied `checkout`. I've edited my answer consequently.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to merge your myfeature branch to master after your task is done. You should have done it directly using `git merge` rather than `git rebase`

It is highly recommended not to use git rebase, since it overwrites the git history. You can read more about the difference and how to use it and why not to use git rebase in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/git-merge-vs-rebase-whats-the-diff-76413c117333)

Now coming to your problem.

You should follow these steps to merge your work.

- Finish your work on the newfeature branch and do a commit
- Checkout to master
- Do a `git pull` of master and sync with remote server.
- Now perform `git merge` on your local or on the remote server, if you are using gitlab, there is a merge request UI which is very helpful and easy to work on.
- If you do it on local then commit the changes and then push it.